# DC-DC Converter usual tolerance

Tags: dc-dc-converter, tolerance

I wonder what the usual voltage tolerance is for a low power (approx. 1-20 W) Buck converter (over its whole operating temperature range).

So far I have found values around +/- 1.5 %

**What is your experience?** Are there IC's with better ratings or is a linear regulator the choice if 1.5 % is not good enough?

Comment: My experience is that I trawl through data sheets analysing and make a error comparison.

Comment: :) I'd rather know before if it is worth it..  Parametric search at TI's web page does not provide an appropriate filter :/

Comment: In case you are asking for product recommendations when you say this --> *Are there IC's with better ratings* <-- questions like this are off topic.

Comment: Definitely not, I am just asking what the experience is and if I shall invest my time into searching through all the datasheets.

Comment: 1.5% sounds about the right ballpark for a couple hundred amp vcore rail on a modern GPU (1v comes out within 0.985 to 1.015v). Not sure about that power range, but if even higher power applications hit it then seems reasonable that products exist.